# how to enable GPU in Windows Azure VM

Tags: azure, gpu, azure-virtual-machine

I am wondering how to enable GPU in my Azure VM, appreciate your help!

I provisioned a Windows Server 2019 Data Science VM which is Standard NC6_Promo (6 vcpus, 56 GiB memory) and has 12G GPU. Based on Azure menu as below NVIDIA CUDA drivers should have been pre-installed.

[image]

But when I check "Task Manager" -> "Performance" I could not see GPU status, I tried to click "View" but there is no choice for "GPU". 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its related to version of WDDM.

Option 1

You can check which version of WDDM your GPU driver is using by pressing Windows+R, typing “dxdiag” into the box, and then pressing Enter to open the DirectX Diagnostic tool. Click the “Display” tab and look to the right of “Driver Model” under Drivers. If you see a “WDDM 2.x” driver here, your system is compatible. If you see a “WDDM 1.x” driver here, your GPU isn’t compatible.

Hope below links helps
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOo73cyeMUU  - Dont worry it mentions about windows 10 but same will work for Windows 2019
https://www.howtogeek.com/351073/how-to-monitor-gpu-usage-in-the-windows-task-manager/

Option 2

[GPUZ](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/), a free tool, will allow you to check your Intel GPU utilization in Windows Server versions, which lack the GPU info in Task Manager.

Comment: Thank you Raju for your help. I just checked for option 1 - "Driver Model" is "unknown", and in task manager "Processes" and "Performance" tabs "GPU" and "GPU engine" both are grayed out. I will have to install GPUZ, but am just curious why "GPU" option is grayed out?  torch.cuda.is_available() is showing GPU is availabe.